# Availability of Azure VM size instances

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

Some Azure VM sizes are not available for some regions. What confuses me is what this depends on. 
I made a direct comparison with a work colleague and the displayed available vms were different. We created a free tier account for each to make a direct comparison.

What could be the reason for this? What information or setting is causing this?

Comment: What specific instance sizes, in what regions? Availability depends on where you are making this request, and what local demand is.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Server Fault has no more visibility into a cloud's capacity or operations than you do.

Try a different region. Try a different instance size. Check [status pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview) or other official channels for what is going on.  Open a support case if this is not a known issue, or you need options customized to your use case.

Recently, (March 2020) Azure observed significantly increased demand. Free accounts may be limited.

> ### [Update #2 on Microsoft cloud services continuity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/)
>
> We’re implementing a few temporary restrictions designed to balance
>   the best possible experience for all of our customers. We have placed
>   limits on free offers to prioritize capacity for existing customers.
>   We also have limits on certain resources for new subscriptions. These
>   are ‘soft’ quota limits, and customers can raise support requests to
>   increase these limits. If requests cannot be met immediately, we
>   recommend customers use alternative regions (of our 54 live regions)
>   that may have less demand surge.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase my earlier answer (which was seen as a question..) - in order to properly see the availability of Azure instances in a particular region it would be best to use the Azure CLI or Powershell.

In my experience the portal experience is far from ideal and might yield false results.

The availability of instance families in general is available hardware in a certain region and or availability zone - machines with the same instance families and sizes will run on specific hardware clusters inside the MS datacenters).

Whether you will be able to launch an instance from an available instance family will indeed depend on the actual availability of resources ( which have been impacted by the surge in cloud usage).